# Structure of a Web Server

Tags: web-server

Where is possible to find references (links or books) about how a generic Web Server work? Basically, I'd like to have a general understanding of what a Web Server does and (ideally) how to create/modify one, say implementing secure `https` connection in a web server that does not support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arstechnica has good tutorial with a fair amount of background info and links to more in-depth articles on various subjects.

http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2012/11/how-to-set-up-a-safe-and-secure-web-server/

The article chooses and focuses on one particular web server (nginx). Unfortunately it doesn't dig into SSL/https configuration.

Be prepared that web servers are a big subject and SSL/https is a big subject all by itself.

For a resource that expects a bit more background knowledge Apache has some great documentation.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/

As you might expect the 'Getting Started' guide might be a great place to start.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/getting-started.html

If you don't mind paying for a service http://www.safaribooksonline.com/ can give you a wealth of good books on the subject for a flat monthly fee.

Comment: thanks a lot. The thing is, more then learning how to configure and use a web server I am after a kind of book describing the main pieces of it at a "code level", in order to make the reader able to eventually create a brand new web server from scratch. I don't know if it's clear

Comment: In that case I'd suggest taking a look at some other posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338775/how-do-i-write-a-web-server-in-c-on-linux